# How to delete the value of a column according to the conditions and increase the number of other columns

Tags: r

I want to delete all the values of n = 1 from the following data and increase that amount to etc.
In addition, I want to delete the column where n was deleted.
How to make it?

Here is my data.

```
사고물질                   n                      
 1 "1"                      1
 2 "1 1-티오비스"           1
 3 "3-부타디엔"             1
 4 "4"                      1
 5 "6 페놀    "             1
 6 "N-뷰틸아크릴레이트"     1
 7 "계면활성제"             1
 8 "과산화물"               1
 9 "과산화수소"             2
10 "etc"                  10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to remove rows where n = 1, and add those observations under "etc".

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dt) #convert to data.table
number <- nrow(dt[n == 1]) #count number of rows where n == 1
dt <- dt[n != 1] #selects rows where n does not equal 1
dt[사고물질 == "etc", n := n + number] #adds number of times n == 1 occured to "etc"
```

Comment: I am not good at English, so I was worried that I might not be able to deliver what I intended, but I think it was delivered well. It works very well. Thanks for your help!